# Can't run write benchmark in Disks (gnome-disks) on Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1

Tags: disk, ubuntu-mate, benchmarks

When I launch `gnome-disks` after clean boot on freshly installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1 and select `Benchmark Disk` with writing enabled, I'm getting `Error unmounting filesystem` error. Is this a normal behavior? Do I have to kill some default system processes manually in order to run write benchmark?

I tested this on i386 laptop and Raspberry Pi 3 with the same result.

Answer (score 4):

Note: Tested on 14.04 and 16.04

This is normal. You can't unmount a filesystem that is in use. On top of that  the [gnome-disks write benchmark is destructive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285139/write-benchmark-of-gnome-disks) and even warns you to backup before using it as shown below:

[image: bench-write]

Due to this you only want to write benchmark disks that don't have important data on them as it will be overwritten. I always boot from live media to benchmark disks with `gnome-disks`

For a safer benchmarking method see my answer using `fio` to a similar question [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/883765/225694)