# How to export disk benchmark result to text?

Tags: disk, benchmarks

I'm benchmarking the usb drive with ubuntu 'disk utility'.

The utility successfully ends the benchmark as below but I need to export the result to text file and analyze it.[image: The benchmark result]

So I dig into some temp files from the utility but failed... :(

Is there any ways to extract the result or find the benchmark result in text form?

Comment: According to [source code](https://sources.debian.org/src/gnome-disk-utility/3.38.2-1/src/disks/gdubenchmarkdialog.c/?hl=434#L332) this is not possible. Possible way is to use some plot digitizer like [engauge-digitizer](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/engauge-digitizer) with the screenshot.

Comment: @N0rbert Really appreciate your comment! I'll try to use an engauge-digitizer though.

Comment: How about fio? @N0rbert https://askubuntu.com/a/883765/15811 :)